# Matlab incorrect out of disk error when compiling script

Tags: matlab, diskspace

I have built a treebagger model in Matlab which I am trying to compile in R2016a using the application compiler. I did this successfully a few days ago, despite the fact that the file for the treebagger model was about 2GB.

I retrained my model because I had made some small changes to my data and now when I try to compile I get an error saying that I am out of disk space, even though I have around 250GB free disk space on the drive. More precisely, the message was "Out of disk space. Failed to create CTF file. Please free -246249051088 bytes and re-run Compiler."

I even retried on a drive with about 2.5TB of free space and got the same issue. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should call Mathworks tech support.